# Deploy C#/C++ binaries incrementally by patching the difference

Tags: windows, deployment, devops, installer, software-patches

My company has a huge C++/C# software system composed of 1800 binaries. The technology range goes from old school native C++ Static Libs, C++/MFC, C++/CLI, up to .NET Framework, .NET Core 3.1, .NET 6/8/etc. Almost all possible Visual Studio project types within this technology range exist in the software.

We struggle to find an optimal way to deploy these binaries at the client by sending them an incremental installer, since slighly changes in the source code may cause binaries to be built very differently.

We sign the DLLs and edit the version info, which also means that a new build of the software results in 1800 different binaries, when actually just a few bytes changed for each binary.

It is very hard to keep track of what source code changes caused exactly the change in the binaries. The complexity of tracking this for inter-related C++ projects is huge, so it is simply not a valid solution for us.

Currently we have an in-house automated PE Header compare system for detecting changes in the binaries from one version to the other, but sometimes it fails to recognize minor changes in some binaries, which sometimes lead to runtime failures.

**Any good ideas, strategies and/or recommendations on how to produce an incremental patch installer for thousands of C++/C# binaries?**

The installer should be as small as possible. Suggestions on 3rd party solutions/frameworks are welcome, since currently Microsoft does not seem to address this issue at all.

Comment: Why specifically do you need incremental patches? Merely to reduce the amount of data that must be transferred to client systems? Or are there other implications for the deployment process?

Comment: The client has multiple servers and thousands of clients, all on-premise. The server distributes new data to all these clients, so it might overload the network infrastructure if we send a 2GB package to every client machine. The client infrastucture is not controlled by us, and it is a critical infrastructure 24/7, it cannot get slow at any moment, and the installation must be performed very fast in all client machines as soon as we decide to start the deployment. This is the reason why we need to send just the differential data.

Comment: From your comment on a question: _"I see that rsync copies the whole file."_ - Wait, are you trying to do delta updates for single binary files? As in, for _a single given DLL file_, you want to skip the bytes that haven't changed - instead of skipping the (whole) files that haven't changed?

Comment: I can't even 100% rule out that that is a good idea, but more in a ["not even wrong"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_even_wrong) way... Have you considered that this might be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: A sensible versioning strategy would *not* require you to change the version of any DLL that hasn't otherwise changed.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: over 600 interrelated C++ projects, it's hard to track changes vs binary changes.

Comment: It could be as simple as checking each file's time stamp.

Comment: The header files are distributed in different directories, not just the project's directory. There is a big chain of includes binding header files together. So it is not easy to track what source files affect exactly a given binary. I cannot change this, since it is a huge software in production and that would be extremely expensive. We are not talking about Disneyland, where everything is build perfectly from the beginning with best software practices. It's an humongous system running since the 90s, and still works well for the client. Advices on source code changes won't help at all.

Comment: Furthermore, we are talking about 1800 projects. VCXPROJ CSPROJ files are built directly with msbuild.exe without Visual Studio SLN files, so we cannot rely on Visual Studio to find out which of the hundreds of C++ projects must be recompiled. A SLN file with over 1800 projects won't even load. Even if it loads, C++ projects contain circular-referenced dependencies. We are talking about hell. The best we can do is to build everything and check new vs. old binaries. Surprisingly, talking to other architect colleagues, I've found out that there are many other companies in the same situation.

Comment: So yes, somehow an XY Problem, to the power of twelve. No easy solution, no way to thrash it, but the incremental deployment problem MUST be solved.

Comment: You might want to check out Raymon Chens articles on the [windows update system](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200213-00/?p=103436)

Comment: Chromium have "courgette" for this, which itself compares against bsdiff: https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/software-updates-courgette/

Comment: via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945075/how-do-i-create-binary-patches

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/patchapi  https://github.com/taspeotis/DeltaCompressionDotNet

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are looking for a tool that can calculate, transfer, and apply binary diffs.

You cannot transfer just modified files, since all files will be modified. However, most parts within the files will stay constant. Thus, such a tool would have to

- split the files into chunks
- check which chunks already exist in the old version
- create a binary diff that only contains the new chunks
- insert the new chunks into the target file

### Rolling hashes for finding matching chunks

A common way to split a file into chunks is a [content-based slicing using a rolling hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash). The rolling hash efficiently calculates a hash over a sliding window of bytes. If we want 2<sup>n</sup> byte large chunks on average, we might draw a chunk boundary whenever the lowest *n* bits of the hash are zero. This is capable of dealing with insertions or moving offsets, unlike splitting chunks at fixed offsets.

Each chunk can be identified by a cryptographic hash. Then, to find changed chunks we merely have to perform a set difference.

Example old bytestream:

```
| ..... | ......... | ..... | ........... |
  4d60    5633        929e    aaee
```

Example new bytestream:

```
| ..... | ..... | ..... | ........... |
  4d60    7a5d    929e    aaee
```

Here, the second chunk changed from hash `5633` to hash `7a5d`. So to update the file on the target system, we only have to transfer the contents of chunk `7a5d`, and have to apply the instruction “replace `5633` with `7a5d`”.

Alternatively, you can slice the new bytestream into fixed-sized chunks, calculate their rolling hash, and use that to efficiently locate instances of the chunks in the old bytestream – essentially a kind of fast substring search algorithm.

Example new bytestream:

```
| .... | .... | .... | .... | .... | .... |
  0c95   147c   676b   ddab   a224   0dc9
```

Example old bytestream containing some of the new chunks:

```
| .... | .. | .... | ...... | .... | .. | .... |
  0c95        676b            a224        ddab
```

Here, four of the chunks are already present in the old bytestream, so that they can be reused when patching the file. Some parts of the file were modified so that chunk `ddab` is now found at a different location, and chunks `147c` and `0dc9` are no longer present. In principle, the location of chunks in the old bytestream could also overlap.

Note that such modifications cannot be performed in-place in a file, since the size or offset of chunks might change. If minimizing downtime is important, create the patched/updates files in a separate directory, and then restart the services from that directory. Compare the concept of [blue–green deployments](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html).

### Application of content chunking and binary diffs in Rsync, Borg-Backup, and Git

The above happens to be exactly what the **`rsync`** tool does with its default “delta encoding” strategy (fixed-sized chunks approach).
Normally, rsync uses an interactive protocol that chops new versions into chunks, then checks which chunks are already available in the old version, and then transfers new data. The new chunks are compressed in transfer.
Rsync also has a **non-interactive batch mode** where the binary diff is calculated once and saved as a file that can then be applied on target system. This seems to be exactly what you're looking for.

Rsync can handle entire directory trees, but any single-file binary diff can be extended to handle **multiple files** if the byte stream being chunked is an archive format that bundles files in a deterministic order, without compressing them separately. For example, uncompressed TAR archives where files are added alphabetically would be suitable. Freshly created ZIP archives without per-file compression would also work.

A similar approach is used by **Git** to synchronize repositories. Git has a concept of “objects” that are identified by hash, for example commits or files. Git can create packfiles in which objects are represented either by their contents, or as a diff: instructions to re-assemble the object contents from other objects. Usually, two repositories are synchronized interactively, by negotiating known objects and then transferring packfiles for the missing objects, which may be expressed as deltas/diffs to existing objects. But again, it is possible to use a non-interactive approach to transfer a packfile manually. With `git bundle create update.pack old..new`, we create a packfile that contains the changes between commits `old` and `new`. The packfile can then be imported in a different repo via `git unbundle update.pack`, as long as that repo already contains the `old` revision. While Git is usually used for text files, the packfiles just deal with opaque binary blobs and use a binary diff for delta compression.

A combination of these approaches (splitting chunks in a content-defined manner by rolling hashes, and content-addressable object storage) is also used by some backup tools such as **Borg-backup/Attic** to enable deduplicated backups. For example, my desktop backup currently covers 640GB of files (495GB compressed). However, most of these chunks do not change and are already present in the backup chunk database. Thus, a typical backup run only needs to transfer about 100MB of data for new chunks, and the entire database of over 30 snapshots spanning more than half a year only takes up 595GB of storage thanks to this content-defined deduplication technique.

There is of course a tradeoff between **chunk size** and overhead for managing chunks. My Borg-backup configuration targets an average chunk size of 2MB, which results in a few million of chunks and a chunk index that is about 100MB large. Rsync handles each file individually, and [dynamically selects a chunk size based on the file size](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/539169), typically around 0.7 to 32KB.

### Applying these techniques to your problem

You may be able to use adapt these tools for your purposes. In particular, Rsync's batch mode should just work. However, these tools were developed in a Unix context, and might not handle some Windows file system features appropriately. If you're already working on the level of writing custom tools to inspect PE headers, you could also consider applying the principles of Rsync's batch mode to your own tools. Such custom tools could also include additional domain knowledge, such as selecting the chunk size so that changed file headers are included entirely in the first chunk with high probability.

Comment: This strategy seems to be a very good solution, because it is totally agnostic to the file types. Much better than the failing strategy of trying to parse complex PE Headers. In this way we can also guarantee that the client has exactly the final files we expect, especially if we perform a hash check on all target files before we start to patch them.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Where we make a cut depends solely on the contents of the sliding window used to calculate the rolling hash. Even if content changes, this doesn't affect the rolling hash after it leaves the window, so later blocks will remain the same. In the method outlined above, the sliding window will be much smaller than the block size. For example, consider each `.` to be one window wide, and what happens when the leading `....` of block `5633` is deleted: the rolling hash will suggest a cut in the same place, but the block ID changes to `7a5d`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman And you're right, I was thinking of `gzip --rsyncable` when writing that explanation. Rsync itself seems to use fixed-size blocks in the new version, and uses the rolling hash to find potential occurrences in the old version,  which are then verified using a cryptographic hash. The existing blocks can then be reused when patching the file. The idea of using the rolling hash to cut blocks is advantageous in a fully offline setting where only one version is available, but not when both the old and new version are available.

Comment: This is exactly what Microsoft's ["Remote Differential Compression"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-rdc/5b027295-0b63-45b9-8f62-0e49448350d9) did - and there _used_ to be a supported API for it that the OP could have used (since the OP's system seems Microsoft-oriented).  But that API [is gone](https://www.ghacks.net/2019/03/07/windows-server-2019-removed-and-deprecated-features/).

Answer (score 10):

I suggest **rsync**. Using rsync you don't need to correctly reimplement vast majority of fuctionality like diff algorithm, working with files, network protocol to transfer data and so on.

> Currently we have an in-house automated PE Header comaparer system to detect changes in the binaries from one version to the other, but sometimes it fails

It's *very strange* that you don't compare file hashes to detect if a file has changed.
It very basic, standard and reliable technique and it far more robust then cryptic "PE checks". **Obviously any part of file may change, not just PE header**.

> **it fails to recognize minor changes in our binaries**, which may result in a catastrophic deployment.

> We don't detect by using hashes obviously because this would always classify all files as being different. The PE Header of all files will always contains different version information, timestamps, and signatures, emitted by the build. So we currently ignore these and deliver the binary only if the rest of the fields are different...Furthermore, some C++ compilers wriite random stuff in some parts of the binary (the parts not contaiining any useful program instruction).

Thats exactly why your deployment is fragile and eventually fail.

> The client has multiple servers and thousands of clients, all on-premise. The server distributes new data to all these clients, so it might overload the network infrastructure if we send a 2GB package to every client machine.

**This is what rsync is made for.**

**You may run rsync as a server to efficiently update files on clients over network directly from the server.**

https://www.mankier.com/1/rsync#Starting_an_Rsync_Daemon_to_Accept_Connections
https://www.mankier.com/1/rsync#Batch_Mode

man rsync

> It is famous for its delta-transfer algorithm, which reduces the amount of data sent over the network by sending only the differences between the source files and the existing files in the destination.  Rsync is widely used for backups and mirroring and as an improved copy command for everyday use.

Using rsync you be able to get binary diffs between two files or two directories and apply them on client machine.

In simpliest scenario you may update all files with one rsync command if all your binaries are under a single directory.

```
# on machine with new files
rsync -r --checksum --compress-choice=zstd --include='*.exe' --include='*.dll' --exclude='*' --only-write-batch=diff_file /deploy/current/ /deploy/previous

# transfer diff_file to client with your installer

# on client
rsync --read-diff=diff_file /path/where_binaries_are/
```

You may write simple program/script to get update logic you needs like process each file individually.

https://www.mankier.com/1/rsync#--write-batch

rsync binaries for windows
https://jl-workshop.com/RSync-for-Windows-Free-Download/

https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/rsync https://community.chocolatey.org/api/v2/package/rsync/6.2.5

https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/binaries/GitHub-CI-builds - which needs dlls from cgwin project.

.NET
https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/Octodiff
https://www.nuget.org/packages/FastRsyncNet/

Also
Delta Compression Application Programming Interfaces
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb417345(v=msdn.10)

bsdiff, xdelta, rdiff

Comment: We don't detect by using hashes obviously because this would always classify all files as being different. The PE Header of all files will always contains different version information, timestamps, and signatures, emitted by the build. So we currently ignore these and deliver the binary only if the rest of the fields are different. But the PE Header is gigantic, and very difficult to understand, even using good parsers like PE.NET. Furthermore, some C++ compilers wriite random stuff in some parts of the binary (the parts not contaiining any useful program instruction).

Comment: I see that rsync copies the whole file. The assumption that we would deliver the whole package of binaries to the client is wrong, given that all hashes are different. The solution I'm looking for should deliver just what has changed. And by that I mean to compute the in-file difference, and send just this difference, for every file which has changed.

Comment: @sɐunıɔןɐqɐp If "random stuff" (which is not actually random) is a big enough issue, you may want to consider a build system or other strategies that assure you of [reproducible builds](https://reproducible-builds.org/). Then, you can rsync to your heart's content, because if the actual input code/version were equivalent, then the output is as well.

Comment: @gapsf: No I've never heard of an Windows implementation, so I'll try it out. Btw, the rsync windows binaries cannot be download from that website, do you know any other reliable website for downloading it?

Comment: https://community.chocolatey.org/api/v2/package/rsync/6.2.5 its just a zip file. There are no official binary releases. There is https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/binaries/GitHub-CI-builds/ which needs dlls from cgwin project.

Answer (score 1):

***My feedback***

Thanks @amon and @gapsf for the provided solutions. My experience so far is:

**(1) Patching Algorithm**

**BsDiff 4**, a nice algorithm originally written in C++ and probably already ported to C#, can be used for implementing a deployment system which finds binary differences for individual existing modified files, no matter what the file extension is. For other files which shouldn't exist either before or after the patch, simply adding them or removing them accordingly is enough. Everything can be packed into a compressed file and manipulated with your own patch installation system. Easy.

To make sure the patch system creates the new binary directory perfectly, a list with hashes of **all files expected to be modified by the patch**, and another list with hashes of **all files expected after the patch has completed** should be good enough for the validation of the patching process.

**(2) Deployment**

In case of any issues with your patching (for whatever reason you may possibly imagine), my preferred approach so far is first to construct the new binary directory separately. After it is consistently generated, there are two possible approaches:

**(2a)** **Move the old binary directory to a fallback backup folder. Afterwards move the newly constructed binary directory to the official location.** But you may not be able to guarantee that no one is using a file located inside your binary directory (e.g. another user from another computer in your network), which could block a directory move operation.

**OR**

**(2b)** Alternatively, **use a junction link as your official binary directory**. It points to the current binary directory (e.g. a directory location out of sight of the user). If the junction link points to the '**bin_v1.0**' binary directory, it can be modified during the deployment for pointing to the '**bin_v2.0**' binary directory through an one-shot command line, using the tool **ln.exe**. This prevents any running binary or any open file inside your current binary directory from blocking your deployment process. It however **does not end the execution of any binaries which started to run prior to your deployment**, and may cause software runtime inconsistencies. Either your software must be able to detect when a new version is deployed, or you kill all instances of it on all machines.

After deploying, you may want to check for deprecated binary directories with older versions of your software, and delete them as convenient.

**(3) Remarks**

If any severe issue happens to your software, a simple rollback can be performed, using any existing binary directory containing a previous version of it.

Just in case your samba cache does not work well with the junction link, a possible workaround is writing a new dummy file inside the root directory where your junction link points to (you must use the junction link as part of your dummy file path). This should trigger a samba cache update.

**References**

- The **BSDiff 4** algorithm is described in the paper: *Colin Percival, Naive differences of executable code*, http://www.daemonology.net/bsdiff/, 2003.
- The command line tool **ln.exe** can be found at: https://schinagl.priv.at/nt/ln/ln.html